# How to segue to different ViewController properly

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

Hello I have code set up that should correctly segue from GameScene to another view controller, mainMenuViewController.  The code I have set up to achieve this is

```
var viewController: GameViewController!
func segue() {
    viewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    SettingsViewController.delete(self)
}
```

In GameViewController

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let skView = view as! SKView
    let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
    //skView.showsPhysics = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)        
    scene.viewController = self
}

}
```

which is called when a SKLabelNode is tapped.  I received advice to use this since the mainMenu is the scene that is first loaded when the player starts the game and they segue to gameScene so I was told to dismiss GameScene instead of creating a new segue every time.  I get the error 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' and a crash whenever the button is tapped.  I assume it is talking about the viewController.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand correctly your problem, you are trying to dismiss GameViewController. But method dismissViewControllerAnimated only dismisses controller that you are currently presenting. So as your game view controller is not presenting anything it can't dismiss it. As you say from code to GameViewController dismiss controller that was presented by him, it tries to do as you want so he gets his property of presented view controller and try to dismiss it, but that property is nil so such error gets. To fix this problem you should call  `viewController.presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` . 
Property presentingViewController returns controller that presents you, in your case controller that present GameViewController. As you get this controller you can dismiss controller that was presented by him(in you case presented controller is your GameViewController). So logic is to get as to say "parent" controller that has permissions to dismiss yourself(GameViewController)

Comment: now I get the long error '*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[Noble_Ninja.SettingsViewController delete:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10011c990'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x186074f5c 0x19ab7bf80 0x18607bb64 0x186078c14 0x185f7cdcc 0x1000f90f4 0x1000f9c4c 0x1000f9d8c 0x18b433a2c 0x18b6016e0 0x18b5faac0 0x18b5cba10 0x18b5c9efc 0x18602c5a4 0x18602c038 0x186029d38 0x185f58dc0 0x1910ac088 0x18b632f44 0x1001115e8 0x19b3a68b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException'

Answer (score 1):

I need to look to your code. It seams now that you try to call method delete  to view controller, but as I know view controller doesn't have such. So think that is other bug in your program, and mainly you are setting Noble_Ninja.SettingsViewController to other object that expect to have such method. That is my prediction I can't say anything clearly because i only has exception description. Try to find where you calling this method in your code , than put brakepoints there and when program stops on your brakepoint write in your console(log) - (po NAME_OF_INSTANCE_THAT_CALLS_SUCH_METHOD) -, it will show real instance type, so with this info you can detect where is real problem. Good luck